# I tried to send an SMS using Twilio in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api

I wrote a code in Python 2 to send an sms, but I got an error.

```
from Twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "secret"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "secret"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="", #a number 
    from_="", #twilio's numbe
    body="welcome to zadly")

print(message.sid)
```

I expected that I would receive SMS but my output was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\send_sms.py", line 13, in <module>
    body="welcome to zadly")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\message\__init__.py", line 87, in create
    data=data,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 209, in create
    raise self.exception(method, uri, response, 'Unable to create record')
TwilioRestException: 
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST /Accounts/ACe927e239a57716562b26844cf015dda8/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49mUnable to create record: Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number: +966509493238.[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21408[0m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21408) and read this -

> If you wish to send messages to this region, please enable the relevant permissions on your account in the [Global Permissions](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/international/sms) page.

Now go click on **Global Permissions** link and enable the relevant permission to send the sms. It's rather simple.

**Ps:** Always read your exceptions carefully, there's clue in there ;)